# SQL query order by column asc/desc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an ecommerce site. On the site I do a query to get all of the products in a category based on price and this works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pricing.product_id
FROM pricing INNER JOIN
     product_categories
     ON pricing.product_id=product_categories.product_id
WHERE product_categories.category_id='?'
ORDER BY pricing.base_price ASC
```

The issue I have is for products with multiple SKUs or variations. So in my pricing table there will be the same product id in as many rows as there are variations and each will have it's own base price.

My issue happens when one variation of one product is more expensive than the one that would generally be dearer.

What I want to know is if there is a way to order it so it is not by the lowest base price of all SKUs but the lowest base price for all SKUs with that product ID.

Comment: Your question would make a lot more sense with sample data and desired results.

Comment: you can order by two values `ORDER BY pricing.product_id ASC, pricing.base_price ASC";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MIN(base_price)` to get the minimum price for each SKU, and order by that.

```
SELECT pricing.product_id
FROM pricing INNER JOIN
     product_categories
     ON pricing.product_id=product_categories.product_id
WHERE product_categories.category_id='?'
GROUP BY pricing.product_id
ORDER BY MIN(pricing.base_price) ASC
```